# Can't use ToString() in LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

So I have the following code:

```
string searchQuery = collection["query"];    
var srmas = (
    from SRMAs in db.SRMAs
    join SRMAStatus in db.SRMAStatus on SRMAs.Id equals SRMAStatus.Id
    join PurchaseOrders in db.PurchaseOrders on SRMAs.PONumber equals PurchaseOrders.PONumber
    join Suppliers in db.Suppliers on PurchaseOrders.SupplierID equals Suppliers.SupplierID
    join SRMADetails in db.SRMADetails on SRMAs.Id equals SRMADetails.SRMAId
    where ids.Contains(SRMAs.Status) 
    && 
    (
        searchQuery.Contains(PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber)
        ||
        searchQuery.Contains(SRMAs.PONumber.ToString())
    )
    select new
    {
        SRMAs.Id,
        SRMAs.PONumber,
        SRMAs.CreatedOn,
        Suppliers.SupplierName,
        SRMAStatus.StatusName,
        PurchaseOrders.PODate, PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber
    }
).ToList();
```

Where `searchQuery` is a string variable.

I have to actually use `IN` clause ofr `PONumber` and for that purpose I am using `Contains` which gives error mentioned in title. How do I check non String values?

Comment: What is `searchQuery`?

Comment: @ekad it is a string variable.

Comment: what's the type of `SRMAs.PONumber`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could give [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) a shot, it'll marry you to sql server and requires .Net 4+

```
searchQuery.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)SRMAs.PONumber))
```

the function seems a little twitchy, when I was spinning up a sample I had to convert my int to a decimal to avoid a Ambigious Invoication build error.

Answer (score 0):

One apporach would be to convert `searchQuery` to the numeric datatype that the `PONumber` is, and you are all set.

Comment: Problem is that user could enter either Numeric or String in Search Box

Comment: @Volatil3 You can parse the user input first.

Answer (score 0):

EF 4 does not support ToString() Method on queries. Either you need to update it to EF6 or you can use SqlFunctions.StringConvert function as follows.

```
string searchQuery = collection["query"];    
var srmas = (
    from SRMAs in db.SRMAs
    join SRMAStatus in db.SRMAStatus on SRMAs.Id equals SRMAStatus.Id
    join PurchaseOrders in db.PurchaseOrders on SRMAs.PONumber equals PurchaseOrders.PONumber
    join Suppliers in db.Suppliers on PurchaseOrders.SupplierID equals Suppliers.SupplierID
    join SRMADetails in db.SRMADetails on SRMAs.Id equals SRMADetails.SRMAId
    where ids.Contains(SRMAs.Status) 
    && 
    (
        searchQuery.Contains(PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber)
        ||
        searchQuery.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SRMAs.PONumber))
    )
    select new
    {
        SRMAs.Id,
        SRMAs.PONumber,
        SRMAs.CreatedOn,
        Suppliers.SupplierName,
        SRMAStatus.StatusName,
        PurchaseOrders.PODate, PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber
    }
).ToList();
```