# Expression to compare Guid properties versus String values and then translate to TSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, reflection, expression-trees

Im working with an very basic expression tree generator to create SQL expressions.

For example, to create an expression for an hypothetical class `User` comparing an `String` property called "Name" vs. an `String` value "john", I use a piece of code similar to this:

```
var propertyInfo = typeOf(User).GetProperties().First(p=>p.Name=="Name");

Expression.Call(
    Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "val"), propertyInfo), 
    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), 
    Expression.Constant("john")
)
```

Which generates (after some lines of code and `EF` intervention) something similar to:

```
[...] Name LIKE '%john%' [...]
```

My problem is with `Guid` properties...

I cannot figurate how should construct the expression to compare a `Guid` property vs. an `String` value, to generate a very simple `SQL` query similar to :

```
[...] Id='38EB4D06-E50B-4C7A-80FF-A6350051682A' [...]
```

I cannot use the `Equals` method between `Guid` and `String`... Im really clueless, any suggestion will be well received...

Comment: You could try `ToString()` to convert the Guid to a string

Comment: I tried with [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) because `ToString()` [is not implemented on LinQ for Entities Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146272/cant-use-tostring-in-linq-to-entities-query), but only accept numbers as parameters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
    var propertyInfo = typeof(Entity).GetProperties().First(p => p.Name == "Id");       

    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entity));
    var propertyAccessExpr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(paramExpr, propertyInfo);
    var guidExpr = Expression.Constant(Guid.Parse("38EB4D06-E50B-4C7A-80FF-A6350051682A"));
    var body = Expression.Equal(propertyAccessExpr, guidExpr);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(body, paramExpr);

    Console.WriteLine(lambda); // Param_0 => (Param_0.Id == 38eb4d06-e50b-4c7a-80ff-a6350051682a)
```

where `Entity` is:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4H4Ahg).

Comment: Works like a charm @Dennis!, basically `Expression.Constant(Guid.Parse("38EB4D06-E50B-4C7A-80FF-A6350051682A"))` was the _magic_ part... Thx !

Comment: After long hours of searching, I can safely say, I love you!